# cannot parse using Parse::Lex

Tags: perl

I am using Perl version 5.12.4 from active state on Windows XP(Version 5.1.2600).Installed ParseLex 2.20.
Trying to run this code from Pro Perl Parsing book from Apress.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Parse::Lex;

#defines the tokens
@token=qw(  
BegParen [\(]
EndParen [\)]
Operator [-+*/^]
Number   [-?\d+|-?\d+\.\d*]
);
$lexer=Parse::Lex->new(@token); #Specifies the lexer
$lexer->from(STDIN); #Specifies the input source

TOKEN:
while(1){ #1 will be returned unless EOI
$token=$lexer->next;
if(not $lexer->eoi){
    print $token->name . " " . $token->text . " " . "\n";
}
else {last TOKEN;}
}
```

As this was not working I simplified by Number   [-?\d+].
It is telling me "Can't call method "name" on an undefined value ".It is not recognizing $token->name & $token->text.
What I am missing here? Please help.

As per Alexandar's suggestion I have changed the code to $lexer->from(*STDIN); and able to successfully read from stdin.Also changed Number   [(-?\d+)|(-?\d+.\d*)].Now when I feed 43.4*15^2 to the STDIN the output I get is:

```
Number 4
Number 3
Number .
Number 4
Operator *
Number 1
Number 5
Operator ^
Number 2
Can't call method "name" on an undefined value at listing1-1.pl line 20, <STDIN>.
```

Here line 20 is print $token->name, " ", $token->text,"\n".

Comment: What input are you trying to parse?

Comment: The error is caused by newline in your input string. I recommend to add `WS \s+` token to parse those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be "Number   -?\d+|-?\d+.\d*" and to read from STDIN "from" method should be called this way:

```
$lexer->from(\*STDIN);
```

**Update** full code with better error handling and fixes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Parse::Lex;

#defines the tokens
my @token=(qw(  
BegParen [\(]
EndParen [\)]
Operator [-+*/^]
Number   -?\d+(?:\.\d*)?
NEWLINE  \n
     ),
     qw(ERROR  (?s:.*)), sub {
       print STDERR "ERROR: buffer content->", $_[0]->lexer->buffer, "<-\n";
       die qq!can\'t analyze: "$_[1]"!;
     }
);
my $lexer=Parse::Lex->new(@token); #Specifies the lexer
$lexer->from(\*STDIN); #Specifies the input source

TOKEN:
while(1){ #1 will be returned unless EOI
  my $token=$lexer->next;
  if (not $lexer->eoi){
    print $token->name . " " . $token->text . " " . "\n";
  }
  else {last TOKEN;}
}
```

Also see [Parse::Lex documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse::Lex).

Comment: Your suggestion about reading from STDIN was perfect.Now I am feeding it 43.4*15^2 at the STDIN and getting the output----------------------Number 4
Number 3
Number .
Number 4
Operator *
Number 1
Number 5
Operator ^
Number 2
Can't call method "name" on an undefined value at E:/indigoworkspace/properlparsing/listing1-1.pl line 20, <STDIN> line 1.Line 20 is print $token->name, " ", $token->text,"\n".

Comment: Thanks Alexandr,it works like a breeze.Now I have better understanding.